# Wpf collapse item in ItemsControl with animation (slideToggle for example)

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, slidetoggle, itemscontrol

I have:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Blocks}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Class Block has properties `string Name` and `bool Visible`.
What to add to this xaml to animate item disappearingand appearing when Visible property is changed? (for example by decreasing/increasing Height of item - slideToggle)

Comment: You can use a `Storyboard`. Have you looked into it?

Comment: of course. But! What to animate? HeightProperty? Okay, but To what value? When we hide - to 0. But when we show? I don't know what Height of item should be.

Comment: When switching to visible, just animate `From="0"` and leave `To` unspecified to animate to the current height.

Comment: It says that it can't animate property "Height" of "StackPanel" with "DoubleAnimation", because DoubleAnimation can't work with NaN. But when I specify concrete values to To and From - it works. But of course I can't specify concrete values of Height, because items should have different heights...

Comment: okay. Another option is to do fadeIn/fadeOut. But how to Collapse Visibility in the end of animation? (in xaml)